# Splitting Audio Files with Matlab

Tags: matlab

How do you split an audio file into multiple parts using MATLAB ? Like I have an audio file composed of ten-twenty notes of a Piano, I need to split it into individual notes and store each note in a separate variable . Is it possible to do this with MATLAB ,if so how ? Can anyone please help me on this ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do the splitting visually you can try "Simple Audio Editor" available in the file exchange.

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19873-simple-audio-editor

I am the author of this program. Let me know if something does not work with that.

You can also try a free audio editor like audacity and export individual pieces to audio files. You can read each piece in MATLAB separately.

If you are looking to achieve this automatically you might need to ask this question in a Signal processing group.